# Populate the data in drop-down from a GET json response- Angular4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-options

I am trying to show json keys/fields in a dropdown for commands; which is Object type(see json below) 
Eg: "key1","key2" should appear in dropdown. Initially used *ngfor but it gives error- "ngfor only supports binding for iterables such as Arrays".
Since my json doesn't contain Array, so tried using ng-options in  but not able to populate the dropdown.  My json looks like:

```
{
    id: ‘bla’,
    commands: {
        “key1” : { },
        “key2”: { }
    }
}
```

html code:

```
<select ngModel="selectedName" ng-options="cmd for cmd in cmdJson" name= "CapabilityCmd" required>
```

In Typescript code:

```
this.http.get(URL, options)
      .pipe(map ((response) => response.json()))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.commandResponse = res;
        this.cmdJson = this.commandResponse.commands;
        console.log("commands:", this.cmdJson);
      });
```

I notice that cmdJson is showing the correct response(i.e;

{“key1” : { },
 “key2”: { }}

) in console but not populating in drop-down box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **`no`** ng-options available in angular, you are using angularjs syntax, instead use **`ngFor`**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedName">
    <option *ngFor="let cmd of cmdJson" [value]="cmd ">
      {{cmd}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sure, but that's what I found on online tutorials /blogs for the scenario I'm running into based on my json. I had already tried this way using ngFor, gives error-

 " Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."


Thanks for quick reply though!

Comment: I end up storing the objects as an array, using Object.keys that returns the json keys in an array and then use *ngFor to show the value in dropdown. That works !